# Can not find data from the dbcontext with linq

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to develop a "password reset" functionality.  To achieve this, I am generating a guid when a user requests a password reset and send this as an email, with a link to the password reset page, that has the guid as a query string. 
The code I have written is below:

```
Request.QueryString[BusinessLayerConstants.resetPasswordQueryString]) ? Request.QueryString[BusinessLayerConstants.resetPasswordQueryString] : String.Empty;
    passwordCode = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(passwordCode);

    using (DBEntities entities = new DBEntities())

    {

    User = entities.AspNetUsers.FirstOrDefault(u => u.PasswordReset == passwordCode);

    if (User != null)
    {
        //TODO
    }
}
```

The problem is, linq always returns null. If I run a SQL command in the database with the same guid, I am able to see the data. And the passwordCode variable is getting the right value as well. I have even checked if the passwordCode has some hidden characters because it is coming from the query string; but it is also fine.

I am also using this exact same logic for activation as well. I am passing a guid as a query string, and for activation, I am able to find the data with the following code:

```
AspNetUser user = entities.AspNetUsers.FirstOrDefault(u => u.ActivationCode == activationCode);
```

It is not working for the password, I have also tried using `.Equals()` and `.Contains()` with no luck.

If anyone has any idea what might be wrong, I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

EDIT: 
PasswordReset is just some GUID I generate to pass as a querystring.
Everything is fine when I do this:
[image: Running some sql]

But in the code, the code I have written returns null:
[image]

Comment: what is `u.PasswordReset`? could it be encrypted/hashed and therefore not the same as `passwordCode`?

Comment: There is a high chance that `PasswordReset` is not what you actualy think it is. Try checking the value of that property again to be sure.

Comment: @user1666620 it is not encrypted, it is the guid I am generating myself.@Hopeless, It is the thing I think what it is, because I am able to see it in the db. If I do something like this: SELECT 
  FROM [AspNetUsers] where PasswordReset like 'cf8d0488-1f60-4ab0-9801-035fbc6bc58873eea9b1-e557-4744-82a5-2b152ea67db0', Then I am able to find the data.

Comment: For testing you can check which users do you have in the database `var Users = entities.AspNetUsers.ToList();` and then check which `PasswordReset` settings do they all have. In production you should not read all users from the database without filter.

Comment: @AlexanderW, I also did this, For example if I get the data filtering by email; then I can see the PasswordReset field is the same string with the passwordCode.

Comment: @biseibutsu, what about the type of the field `PasswordReset`, is it `string` ?

Comment: @AlexanderW, yes it is. And it is nvarchar(256) in the database.

Comment: @biseibutsu you wrote:"For example if I get the data filtering by email; then I can see the PasswordReset field is the same string with the passwordCode". What about the follow test: `UsersWithEmail = GetByEmail(...); UsersWithPwdReset = UsersWithEmail.FirstOrDefault(u => u.PasswordReset == passwrodCode);` This way you compare it on the client side, not on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that C# is case sensitive you should do like:

```
Request.QueryString[BusinessLayerConstants.resetPasswordQueryString]) ? Request.QueryString[BusinessLayerConstants.resetPasswordQueryString] : String.Empty;
    passwordCode = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(passwordCode);

    using (DBEntities entities = new DBEntities())

    {

    User = entities.AspNetUsers.FirstOrDefault(u => u.PasswordReset.ToLower() == passwordCode.ToLower());

    if (User != null)
    {
        //TODO
    }
}
```

Comment: No, everything is already lowercase; But I tried it anyway, It didn't work.

Comment: this is completely unrelated and personal, may I ask if you are Turkish? I have problem with translation of my website and need help. seeing your linked in link I thought you might be Turkish

Comment: using a break point check if the `passwordCode` have the desired value the moment it is compared

Comment: As far as I know, FirstOrDefault() if called in context of EF, it will be translated to database query and therefore is case-insensitive, so there's no need to call ToLower() actually. Of course it's different if you bring all database records into memory and use Linq to Object

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani, I am Turkish but I hardly have time anything, I sorry. and I have added a screenshot you can actually see that I am checking the value at runtime as well.

Comment: @biseibutsu change `user.PasswordReset != String.Empty` to `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.PasswordReset)`

Comment: When I speak Turkish, Even the Turks won't notice that I'm not Turk but I have problem with formal sentences. I thought we might be able to help each other on our projects

Comment: I would have liked to help, I didn't mean to be rude, I just don't have any time.

Comment: @PhuongNguyen I think string comparison on database side is case-sensitive or not depends on the so-called database ***collation*** (or even collation applied on just some table or column).